# Reduce queries in Rails request for multiple association levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have four models that I am working with

- Collection
- Album
- Photo
- ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag

Basically I am outputting a list of Collections, each one shows its Albums and I wish each Album to list all the tags that its containing Photos have.

I currently have tried this query:

```
@collections = Collection.all.includes(albums: [photos: [:tags]])
```

It sort of helps but is still pulls out each tag separately by the looks of the log lines like:

> ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE
> "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND
> "taggings"."context" = $3  [["taggable_id", 85803], ["taggable_type",
> "Photo"], ["context", "tags"]] 23:10:56 web.1     |   ↳
> app/views/admin/gallery/gallery/index.html.erb:284

Any ideas how to make this more efficient and faster?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but have you tried. `Collection.eager_load(albums: {photos: :tags})` this should load all the associations in a single query (although I am not sure if it will work with the Polymorph)